# Send Activity Reminders to Users

Tags: reporting, tasks

I'd like to send an email/report to all users once a week listing their upcoming overdue activities (tasks).  If the report is sent to John, Jane, and Bob, each one only sees their own activities - not the others.

**What's the best way to do this?**

My understanding is that the standard reports scheduler can not handle this, because there's only one "running user", rather than tailoring the view to each recipient.  Native solutions or plugins welcome.

Answer (score 1):

One could build this with some scheduled/batch Apex Code. A simple design could be:

```
global class NotifyImpendingTasks implements System.Schedulable {
    global void execute(System.SchedulableContext sc) {
        Map<Id, Task[]> tasks = new Map<Id, Task[]>();
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messages = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[0];
        User[] users = new User[0];

        for(Task record: [SELECT Id, OwnerId, Subject, ActivityDate FROM Task WHERE IsClosed = FALSE AND ActivityDate = NEXT_N_DAYS:7 ORDER BY ActivityDate ASC]) {
            if(!tasks.containsKey(record.OwnerId)) {
                tasks.put(record.OwnerId, new Task[0]);
            }
            tasks.get(record.OwnerId).add(record);
        }

        users = [SELECT Id, FirstName FROM User WHERE Id IN :tasks.keyset()];

        for(User userrecord: users) {
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            String subject = 'Upcoming tasks this week: '+tasks.get(userrecord.Id).size();
            String message = 'The following tasks are coming up in the next week: \n\n';

            for(Task taskrecord: tasks.get(userrecord.id)) {
                message += datetime.newinstancegmt(taskrecord.activitydate, time.newinstance(0,0,0,0)).formatGMT('MMM dd, YYYY')+': '+taskrecord.subject+'\n';
            }

            email.setTargetObjectId(userRecord.Id);
            email.setSubject(subject);
            email.setPlainTextBody(message);
            email.setSaveAsActivity(false);
            messages.add(email);
        }
        if(!messages.isEmpty()) {
            Messaging.sendEmail(messages);
        }
    }
}
```

Schedule the class to run on Sundays, and they'll get a weekly itinerary. You could modify the code to also include past due tasks, for example, or tasks that are open with no due date. The sky is the limit with this basic framework. If you expect that you may need to query more than 50,000 records, etc, you might need to break out the logic into a batch class, but that's probably overkill for most organizations.

You can also specify a generic from address and/or display name, if you'd like to make it a little more formal/system-generated-appearing, etc.

Comment: This looks like a great solution.  I just wish SFDC offered something like this more natively :(